# VBA Setting value of cell does not change cell contents in unprotected sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following macro in an Excel Sheet - which retrieves the patient identified by their hospital number and puts there surname in one column and this works fine.

I now need to insert more data in the sheet, but while the surname appears, the other data does not.

I have no problems writing to the same cell, to cells to the left, but when ever I try and write to the columns on the right nothing happens.

The sheet is unprotected, it is not a case of the font and cell background being white. Any ideas?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim Mrn As String

    ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
    ' cause an alert when they are changed. 
    Set KeyCells = Range("C10:C29")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
        Mrn = Target.Text

        If Mrn = "" Then
            Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = ""
        Else
            cn.ConnectionString = "MyConnectionString"
            cn.Open
            Set rs = cn.Execute("Select nhs_surname From nhs_patient_s Where UPPER(nhs_patientid) = '" + UCase(Mrn) + "'")

            If rs.EOF Then
                Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = "UNKNOWN"
            Else
                Do While Not rs.EOF
                    Dim surname As String
                    surname = rs("nhs_surname")
                    Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = surname
                    Target.Offset(, 3).Value = "Now here!!!!"
                    rs.MoveNext
                Loop
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Btw, please don't use [tag:macros] tag that isn't for VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the column where the surname was being put was a merged cell and this affected the offset for the Discharge Date column.

So the solution was simply to use the number 6 rather than 3

```
Target.Offset(, 6).Value = "Now here!!!!"
```

Comment: Please accept an answer if your issue is solved, and a little upvote for the other nice answers is always welcome! ;)

Answer (score 0):

With your loop, you are putting every surname in the same column, use a Range object to move it :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim Mrn As String
    Dim RgToFill As Range

    ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
    ' cause an alert when they are changed.
    Set KeyCells = Me.Range("C10:C29")
    Set RgToFill = Target.Offset(0, 1)

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
        Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
        Mrn = Target.Text

        If Mrn = vbNullString Then
            RgToFill.Value = vbNullString
        Else
            cn.ConnectionString = "MyConnectionString"
            cn.Open
            Set rs = cn.Execute("Select nhs_surname From nhs_patient_s Where UPPER(nhs_patientid) = '" + UCase(Mrn) + "'")

            If rs.EOF Then
                RgToFill.Value = "UNKNOWN"
            Else
                Do While Not rs.EOF
                    Dim surname As String
                    surname = rs("nhs_surname")
                    RgToFill.Value = surname
                    '''Move the range to fill to the next column
                    Set RgToFill = RgToFill.Offset(0, 1)
                    rs.MoveNext
                Loop
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```